# Proper syntax for scraping plugin

Tags: php

I'm using this excellent plugin to scrape some content from a specific website: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm.

An example of what I'm trying to scrape through.

```
    <section class="details">

        <div class="address">  
          <div class="zip-code-country">
              <span>USA</span>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="phone">
            <a href="tel:+1234567890">(123)456-7890</a>
          </div>
          <ul>
              <li><a href="mailto:test@example.com">Email</a></li>
          </ul>
      </section>
```

The relevant part of my code is like this:

```
foreach($html->find('section.details') as $part2) {

    $item2['zip']     = $part2->find('div.zip-code-country span', 0)->plaintext; //works perfectly
    $item2['phone']     = $part2->find('div.phone a', 0)->plaintext; //works perfectly
    $item2['email']     = $part2->find('ul li a[href]', 0)->plaintext; //issue is here
    $pieces2[] = $item2;
}
```

When I try to get `email`, it returns the anchor text (i.e., "Email). What I want is for it to return "test@example.com".

Thoughts on how to get this syntax correct?

Comment: scrapping contact details from a website looks scuzzy

Comment: @rtfm There's a very simple and permitted reason for doing this as a quick MVP without integrating an entire API from the site we're scraping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to do:

```
$email= $part2->find('ul li a[href]', 0)->href;
$item2['email'] =str_replace('mailto:', '', $email);
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.